# Update on Items under ObservableArray NOT propagated to UI

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

update in ObservableArrayItem not updating Ui
I have Knockout model like below

My c# data model looks like this

```
   public class DTO
    {       
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal AmountLeft { get; set; }      
        public TypeDTO[] BType { get; set; }
    }

       public class TypeDTO
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my JS, for initial load it works fine

```
var DetailsViewModel;

   $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {

            for (i = 0; i < result.BType.length; i++) {
                addPercent(result.BType[i], result.Amount);
            }
            DetailsViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
            ko.applyBindings(DetailsViewModel, $("#elem-box").get(0));


    });

function addPercent(BType, totalAmount)  //**adds two new fields to what server sends**
    {
        BType.Percent = ko.computed(function () {

            return ((BType.Amount / totalAmount) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        });

        BType.Ratio = ko.computed(function () {

            return ((BType.Amount / totalAmount) ).toFixed(2);
        });

    }
```

on the initial UI bind it works perfectly. later when I update the array in `DetailsViewModel.BType` in a javascript it does not get update in UI.

trigger on some event passes index of the UI element corresponds to BType array

```
var totalAmount = DetailsViewModel.Amount();

DetailsViewModel.BType()[index].Amount = totalAmount * 10;
DetailsViewModel.AmountLeft = totalAmount - DetailsViewModel.BType()[index].Amount;

addPercent(DetailsViewModel.BType()[index], totalAmount);
```

**Neither of the update made to BType array gets update on UI side nor the update made under addPercent function, on console.log I can see all of the update execute on model side run successfully.    Why arrayItem updates are not propagated to the UI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update individual indices. You need to pass the whole array to the observable so that knockout can run the internal updating code.

```
var bt = DetailsViewModel.BType();
bt[index].Amount = totalAmount * 10;
DetailsViewModel.BType(bt);
```

Comment: but how do you update the computed value under function addPercent?

Answer (score 0):

Further to what [@Robert Krzyzanowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2540303/robert-krzyzanowski) said, you need to follow the following pattern:

```
var typeDTOs = ko.observableArray([]);
var underlyingArray = [];

_.each(result.BType, function(typeDTO) {
    typeDTO = addPercent(typeDTO, result.Amount);
    underlyingArray.push(typeDTO);
}

typeDTOs(underlyingArray);
```

or something to that effect (I used underscore.js above just for clarity).  You want to be sure not push into your *observable* array; instead push into an underlying array.  Then, you can update the observable array all at once.  If you don't do that, you'll wind up firing change events for every item you push into the observable array--usually undesirable.

**Another Note on Observable Arrays**

Just a sidebar...If the elements of your arrays are object literals, and you want your UI to respond to changes in the literal's properties, you must make each UI-bound property an observable as well.